# Merge File using BVR produce Weird Output (refer image attached)

Tags: merge, qgis, esri

I have been trying to merge .tif files that I downloaded from livingatlas.arcgis.com : SENTINEL-2 10M LAND USE/LAND COVER DOWNLOAD [https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/landcover/](https://stackoverflow.com). It is supposed to be a very simple merge step in QGIS > selects the raster tab (or access the processing toolbox) > Merge. Unfortunately, I have got the error that said memoryerror.

I googled to find some solutions, one of them recommended changing the windows settings that could cater the 'memoryerror'. And, it works where run processes mentioned 'merged finished'. But, too bad, it only processes one part of tif files and yet the output is black box. Again, it mentioned something with the memory.

Then, I run a similar merging process using my pc lab (which I am quite sure has plenty of space to run the process). But still the same result appeared. Is this because the height measurement for one of the tif files is different? file A (x:66795 ; y:88550) and file B (x:66795 ; y:88549). Data type, Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer, Band-1.

If that is so, I also tried to use the BVR (Built Visual Raster) that has the function - 'Allow projection difference'. The difference is this time, the merging process is successfully finished with wrongly place of merge map. Attached is the image and the notes related the question for reference. I also noted that the blue color appear on land is representing the NODATA (Notes: For the other grid files, NODATA is only used for areas covered with water, except for the land cover grids, on which water is a separate class -Source of reference [https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata](https://stackoverflow.com)).

[Wrongly Place Merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3lNw.png)

Any idea / suggestion to solve this problem? It already took me more than a week to only do this (study several method to merge .tif using QGIS platform). My version of QGIS 3.22.8 , python 3.9.5, GDAL 3.5.0.

Thank you in advanced.